# A slight variant of the Monty Hall Problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, monty-hall

Suppose that there are 4 doors having 2 cars and 2 goats. You arbitrarily choose a door, then Monty shows a door with a goat. What is the probability of getting a car if you switch. Apparently the answer is 3 / 4. I got it right but the line of thinking I had seems to be wrong. Can anyone give me a very sound explanation how it arrived to 3 / 4? I really want to wrap my head around this concept. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the same logic as computing 2/3 in original Monty Hall. take cases.

Case 1 Goat 1

P(switch gets car in this case) = 1

Case 2 Goat 2

P(switch gets car in this case) = 1

Case 3 Car 1

P(switch gets car in this case) = 1/2

Case 3 Car 2

P(switch gets car in this case) = 1/2

Each case has 1/4 probability of happening.

Hence  P(switch gets car) = (1/4)(1+1+1/2+1/2) = 3/4

---

Btw I'm guessing there maybe a pattern.

In original MH problem, people think the probability is 1/2 when it is really 2/3.

Here, people might think the probability is 2/3 (leftover doors after revealing one goat are 2 cars and 1 goat) when it is really 3/4.

Comment: Thanks! But your solution requires all cases, I want to see if there is a solution that only involves one case then solve it. Like the  concept of probability compression in the Monty Hall problem.

Comment: @JansenLopez wut? https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=probability+compression&oq=probability+compression&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22probability+compression%22

Comment: This is the video that made me understand the Monty Hall Problem. I want a solution to this variant near this video's concept. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Lb-6rxZxx0

Comment: @JansenLopez What is a probability compression? :| TL;DW. Essentially, people think it is 1/2 when really it is 2/3. Similarly, in this case people might think 2/3 when it is really 3/4.

Comment: @JansenLopez Are you referring to the 100 doors thing? I don't see how that's not applicable to this variant?

Comment: Yes I was referring to the 100 doors thing. If u have 100 doors, if say you choose door 1 the probability of that door having a car is 1 / 100. The rest of the remaining doors have a probability of 99 / 100. If Monty opens 98 of the remaining doors the remaining door of the 99 / 100 group will get that probability. This is the compression principle. I think I got the concept wrong thinking if you show one goat the switching probability will already be equal to the probability of the other set (A =  1/ 100, **B = 99 / 100**).

Comment: Its just so happens in the original Monty Hall problem if you show one goat you will have the ONLY remaining door left. To be more clear if you have 4 doors 1 car, 3 goats. Say you choose door 1 it has a probability of 1 / 4 the 3 remaining doors have a probability of 3 / 4. If Monty shows 1 goat the switching probability is not 3 / 4 you have to open one more door that is goat, which leaves us 2 remaining doors the one you chose and the one in the 3 / 4 group, in this scenario if u choose to switch it will have a probability of 3 / 4.

Comment: Um, I'm guessing you got it. Good job! Please accept and upvote. Hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

Our original choice was either a car or a goat. If our original choice was a goat, then the probability that we choose a car once we switch is
$$
\Bbb P(\text{car}\mid\text{goat})=1
$$
If our original choice was a car, then the probability that we choose a car once we switch is 
$$
\Bbb P(\text{car}\mid\text{car})=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Now, given that we decide to switch we have
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P(\text{switch to car})
&=\Bbb P(\text{car}\mid\text{goat})\cdot\Bbb P(\text{goat first})+\Bbb P(\text{car}\mid\text{car})\cdot\Bbb P(\text{car first}) \\
&= 1\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
Since the original probability of choosing a car is $\frac{1}{2}$ we see that switching is the best strategy.

Comment: Can u show me the same mathematical explanation for the original Monty Hall problem?

Comment: @JansenLopez If our original choice was a goat, then the probability that we choose a car once we switch is $\Bbb P(\text{car}\mid\text{goat})=1$. If our original choice was a car, then the probability that we choose a car once we switch is $\Bbb P(\text{car}\mid\text{car})=0$. Now, given that we decide to switch we have $\Bbb P(\text{switch to car})=1\cdot\frac{2}{3}+0\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$.